# MissingResourceException - Java 5, JBoss 5.0, XSLT

Tags: xslt, jboss5.x

I have written sample program which uses XSLT to generate HTML response. Check below files.
welcome.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
<xsl:variable name="myResource" select="java:java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle('com.carbonrider.web.xslt.AppResources')" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<xsl:apply-templates />
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="first">
<h2>
<xsl:value-of select="java:getString($myResource,'hi')" />
</h2>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**PageTransformer.java**

```
package curiousmind.web.xslt;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class PageTransformer extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
try {
DOMSource domSource = createDOMSource();
Transformer transformer = transFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("welcome.xsl")));
Result result = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(response.getWriter());
transformer.transform(domSource, result);
} catch (Exception e) {
throw new ServletException(e);
}
}
private DOMSource createDOMSource() throws Exception {
String xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n<first><second>Hello World</second></first>";
byte[] buf = xmlString.getBytes("UTF-8");
BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buf));
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder domBuilder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document dom = domBuilder.parse(is);
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(dom);
is.close();
return domSource;
}
}
```

When I run above code, I get following error message in console

```
ERROR [STDERR] SystemId Unknown; Line #7; Column #95; java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name curiousmind.web.xslt.AppResources, locale en_US
```

Here is the properties file kept inside curiousmind.web.xslt

**AppResources.properties**

```
hi=Hello World
```

Can anyone please tell me what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to access the resource bundle from same servlet "PageTransformer" by instantiating java.util.ResourceBundle and it worked. This lead to more confusion as why transformer instantiated from same class is not able to get the ResourceBundle instance.
I added xalan.jar file, but it gave same result.

Finally I thought of enabling "-verbose" mode for jboss as to find out, what could be the actual cause. This gave me hint that, when the servlet is getting invoked and it is instantiating Transformer, it is loading xalan.jar file from JBOSS_DIR/lib/endorsed/xalan.jar. I had to finally remove "xalan.jar" and "serializer.jar" file from jboss and my page worked well.

Though this solved problem, I think better approach would be to use "jboss-classloading.xml" to customize the classloading behavior. But couldn't get appropriate configuration for that.